# Is Android Gmail safe from other apps?

Tags: appsec, android, gmail

By "safe" I specifically mean: safe from potential (unauthorized) access of other entities of Android system, such as third party applications.

While it's clear that no app is safe from users (in this case, installing apps from suspicious sources) acceptable safety would imply:

- safe connections (SSL/TLS) to and from server
- password used only once, in order to obtain token, and never stored
- stored email messages **encrypted** or another way to **disallow any other entity** on the OS from **viewing/altering** its content

Comment: Every app runs in its own sandbox and other apps can't access it. But if you give an app root access then it will have access to everything including your mails and saved passwords.

Comment: @defalt I'm aware of that. But question is also if third party app can check for `/path/to/gmail/emails/` and read email contents or not.

Comment: Only if you give that app administrator permission or if it asks for administrator privileges. What app can do in administrator mode is also mentioned in **Android Manifest.xml**. Giving administrator rights is different from giving root access.